# How to measure the latency on my nginx server?

Tags: nginx, scalability, passenger, latency

I'm not sure if I am using the correct term.
I have several Nginx (Passenger plugin) workers rendering my web application (Ruby on Rails).

The thing is that I have no idea on when I should fire up new workers / servers. If my users are using too much of the resources, I guess the requests will start to stack up on nginx, and there will be a delay until they get processed by an nginx worker (depending on availability). So is there a simple way to get those latency values that can give me an idea on when I need to scale up or down?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nginx workers do not render your RoR application. But Passenger do. So, you should tune its options: "[Phusion Passenger users guide: Resource control and optimization options](http://www.modrails.com/documentation/Users%20guide%20Nginx.html#_resource_control_and_optimization_options)"

Comment: Thx, I know that passenger render my rails app through nginx, and also know about the option. My question was how do I know when my workers are overloaded and I need to tune passenger / add more server ? I would like real stats in some ways.

Comment: Use `passenger-status`:
http://www.modrails.com/documentation/Users%20guide%20Nginx.html#_inspecting_phusion_passenger_8217_s_internal_status

Comment: And btw, check your cpu usage (top), if your system is overloaded then more passenger processes will make things even worse.